# Find a factor #1

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, number-theory

<sub>The series of [Find a factor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98520/find-a-factor-1) puzzle is started by [Culver Kwan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/61965/culver-kwan), and asks the solver to identify a factor of a certain large number within a certain range using some mathematical identities. This should be tagged with [mathematics](/questions/tagged/mathematics), [number-theory](/questions/tagged/number-theory) and [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers).</sub>

---

Find a factor of $104060405$ within $10100$ and $11000$, using various mathematical identities. You should not use a computer.

Comment: Does seeing a factorization count as using an identity? This factors easily if you rot13(oernx vg va gur zvqqyr), so to speak.

Comment: @msh210 I do not understand what are you saying, but the identity is a Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be honest, like msh210 said in the comments, I just saw the factorisation:

> $104060405 = 104050000 + 10405 = 10405*(10000+1) = 10405*10001$

You could find it by recognising

> most of the fourth row of Pascal's triangle $1 4 6 4 1$, and using
>  $(x+1)^4=x^4+4x^3+6x^2+4x+1$
>  with $x=100$ to write the number as
>  $104060405=101^4+2^2=10201^2+2^2$

And then applying the identity

> for [the product of sums of two squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity):
>  $10201^2+2^2 = (102*100+1*1)^2+(102*1-100*1)^2 = (102^2+1^2)(100^2+1^2)$

but that seems a bit convoluted to me.

**Edit:**

The intended trick was to use:

> [Sophie Germain's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain#Honors_in_number_theory) which is
>  $x^4+4y^4 = (x^2+2xy+2y^2)(x^2-2xy+2y^2)$
>  In this case we have $x=101$ and $y=1$, so the factors are
>  $101^2\pm 202 + 2 = 10203\pm 202$

Comment: Do you know the Sophie Germain's identity? It is in a small section of a Wikipedia page, but you can see the explanation in other sites. I used this identity to create this problem. Still, your answer is good and a check mark will be rewarded. I will try not to make a question  which can be done with very simple factorisation next time.

Comment: @CulverKwan I was not really aware of that identity. I have no doubt seen it before, but it is not one that I have ever needed so it is not in my arsenal as it were.

Answer (score 1):

The number trivially splits into

> $5 \times 20812081 = 5 \times 10001 \times 2081 = 10001 \times 10405$